# fill a fields in forms with button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I got a problem I need to fill two fields in a form with diffrent values and I would like to do that with an button onClick function.

I genererat buttons and the output looks like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare(test, 1)">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare(test2, 3)">1</button>
```

Now I want to fill my form with the values 
the first value I want to be placed in the first `field id="areaname_fill"` and the secound value should fill the `field id="squarename_fill"`.

Just to clarify, If I click on the first button 
`id="areaname_fill"` should set the value to `"Test"` AND 
`id="squarename_fill"` should set the value to `1`.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>fyll i område</label>
    <input type="text" name="areaname_fill" id="areaname_fill" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>fyll i rutans nummer</label>
    <input type="text" name="squarename_fill" id="squarename_fill" class="form-control" value="" /> 
</div>
```

I came up with this JS but I can't get it to work, any ides?

```js
function fillsquare(area,square)
{
    var area = area;
    var square = square;

    document.getElementById(areaname_fill).value = area;
    document.getElementById(squarename_fill).value = square;
}
```

Comment: `areaname_fill` and `squarename_fill`are strings, you should put them inside quotes (single or double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally recommended that you avoid using inline javascript like `onClick="foo"`

If possible, you should change your markup to to include the values in the [button markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) and then add a [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to extract and the data and use it in the form. Here's an example of that.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const areaField = document.getElementById("areaname_fill");
const squareField = document.getElementById("squarename_fill");

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    areaField.value = button.dataset.area;
    squareField.value = button.dataset.square;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>fyll i område</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="areaname_fill"
    id="areaname_fill"
    class="form-control"
    value=""
  >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>fyll i rutans nummer</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="squarename_fill"
    id="squarename_fill"
    class="form-control"
    value=""
  >
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="test" data-square="1">
  First button
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="test2" data-square="3">
  Second button
</button>
```

Comment: I went with this solution in the end. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it in this way

```
document.getElementById("areaname_fill").value=area;
document.getElementById("squarename_fill").value=square;
```

And here

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare('test', 1)">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare('test2', 3)">1</button>
```

```js
function fillsquare(area,square)
{
    document.getElementById("areaname_fill").value = area;
    document.getElementById("squarename_fill").value = square;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
     <label>fyll i område</label>
     <input type="text" name="areaname_fill" id="areaname_fill" class="form-control" value="">  
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>fyll i rutans nummer</label>
     <input type="text" name="squarename_fill" id="squarename_fill" class="form-control" value="">  
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare('test', 1)">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillsquare('test2', 3)">1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementById("areaname_fill").value=area;
>   document.getElementById("squarename_fill").value=square;

You should Add double quotes to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. The quotes are missing in `onclick` and in the `document.getElementById` as the `test` and `test2` are string, and the `document.getElementById` expects a string argument (the element id).

```js
 function fillsquare(area, square) {
        var area = area;
        var square = square;

        document.getElementById("areaname_fill").value = area;
        document.getElementById("squarename_fill").value = square;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
      onclick="fillsquare('test', 1)"
    >
      1
    </button>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
      onclick="fillsquare('test2', 3)"
    >
      1
    </button>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>fyll i område</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="areaname_fill"
        id="areaname_fill"
        class="form-control"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>fyll i rutans nummer</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="squarename_fill"
        id="squarename_fill"
        class="form-control"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
```